# Compute $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}\sin(x)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

I have to compute$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{e^{-tx}\cdot \sin(x)}{x}dx$$

This is following a helping problem $$\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}\cdot \sin(x)dx$$ which using IPB two times turned out to be $$\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}$$

I think there must be a substitution to get to the first problem, but I just cannot see it. Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define
$$
I = \int \limits_0 ^\infty e^{-tx}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx
$$
then
$$
\dfrac{dI}{dt}=-\int \limits_0 ^\infty e^{-tx}\sin(x)dx = -\frac{1}{1+t^2}
$$
hence
$$
I = -\arctan(t) + D
$$

We fix $D$ using $I(0)=D=\dfrac\pi 2$, easily obtainable through complex analysis.

Comment: You don't need to use complex analysis. Simply note that $I(\infty)=0$ to find $D$. (Now you can plug in $t=0$, giving $I(0)=\frac\pi2$ without complex analysis.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw That's true, easily obtained from $ 0\leq I \leq \int\limits_0^{+\infty}e^{-tx}dx $

Answer (score 4):

We can compute $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-tx}\sin x/x dx$ for a positive $t$. Indeed, define 
$$F(t,x):=\frac{\sin x}xe^{-tx}.$$
If $\delta$ is a positive number, then for any non-negative $x$, $$\sup_{s\geqslant \delta}\partial_tF(s,x)|\leqslant e^{-\delta x}.$$
Since the map $x\mapsto e^{-\delta x}$ is integrable on $[0,\infty)$, we can take the derivative under the integral.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\large\tt\mbox{With}\quad t > 0}$:

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-tx}\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}
> =\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-tx}\pars{\half\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic kx}\,\dd k}
> =\half\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{\pars{\ic k - t}x}\,\dd k
> \\[3mm]&=\half\int_{-1}^{1}{1 \over t - \ic k}\,\dd k
> =t\int_{0}^{1}{\dd k \over t^{2} + k^{2}}
> =\int_{0}^{1/t}{\dd k \over 1 + k^{2}}= \arctan\pars{1 \over t}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\Large{\pi \over 2} - \arctan\pars{t}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} \frac{\sin x}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x &= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} \sin x \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zx} \,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\!\!\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x\left(z+t\right)} \sin x\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\left(z+t\right)^2 +1}\\
&= \left[\lim_{N\to\infty}\arctan(N+t)\right] - \arctan t \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan t\\
&= \operatorname{arccot} t
\end{aligned}
 $$

Comment: Note: We can say that $ \displaystyle{\frac{1}{x} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zx}\,\mathrm{d}z} $ because we are integrating over the interval $(0, \infty)$, i.e., $x>0$, so the integral converges.